# Password protect Excel sheet but allow editing

Tags: excel

I have built an excel spreadsheet that pulls data from another sheet by various Vlookup.  E.g if you type in a number in one cell it pulls back the corresponding Name, job, title etc from the data in the other sheet. 
As this is to be used by others I wanted to Hide the formula so it’s not visible in the formula bar. 
I unlocked all the cells, selected the cells with formula I wanted to hide, locked and hid those cells then protected the sheet. When testing I can enter data in the unlocked field and get results but I also have a reset macro button. When I reset the fields I am unable to enter data as the sheet is protected. Any help on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What does your macro look like? Sounds like you might have a line that protects all cells in there perhaps.

Comment: Hi. Macro is Sub Clearcells() 
'Updateby Extendoffice 20161008 
Range("C11", "C11").Clear 
Range("I11", "K11").Clear 
Range("O11", "O11").Clear 
End Sub

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. You manually locked the cells.  Neither you nor your macro unlock the cells. So it makes sense you get a message stating cells cannot be changed because they are locked.... Why not have your macro unlock the cells so they can be reset and then lock them before ut ends?  What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The data is to be used by other debts to input their employee id and return info about them. The input cell was left unlocked but I wanted to hide the cells with lookup formula. I wanted a reset button so it can be left blank for the next person to use. I thought I would still be able to input to the unlocked cell.